# How can I convert XHTML nested list to pdf with iText?

Tags: pdf, xhtml, itext, nested-lists

I have XHTML content, and I have to create from this content a PDF file on the fly. I use iText pdf converter.
I tried the simple way, but I always get bad result after calling the XMLWorkerHelper parser.

XHTML:

            `<ul>
               <li>First
                   <ol>
                        <li>Second</li>
                        <li>Second</li>
                  </ol>
               </li>
               <li>First</li>
            </ul>`

The expected value:

- First

  1. Second
  2. Second
- First

PDF result:

- First Second Second
- First

In the result there is no nested list. I need a solution for calling the parser, and not creating an iText Document instance.

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at the example [NestedListHtml](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/NestedListHtml)

In this example, I take your code snippet [list.html](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/list.html):

```
<ul>
  <li>First
    <ol>
      <li>Second</li>
      <li>Second</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>First</li>
</ul>
```

And I parse it into an `ElementList`:

```
// CSS
CSSResolver cssResolver =
    XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCssResolver(true);

// HTML
HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
htmlContext.autoBookmark(false);

// Pipelines
ElementList elements = new ElementList();
ElementHandlerPipeline end = new ElementHandlerPipeline(elements, null);
HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, end);
CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

// XML Worker
XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
p.parse(new FileInputStream(HTML));
```

Now I can add this list to the `Document`:

```
for (Element e : elements) {
    document.add(e);
}
```

Or I can list this list to a `Paragraph`:

```
Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
for (Element e : elements) {
    para.add(e);
}
document.add(para);
```

You will get the desired result as shown in [nested_list.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/nested_list.pdf)

You *can not* add nested lists to a `PdfPCell` or to a `ColumnText`. For instance: this will not work:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.addCell("Nested lists don't work in a cell");
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
for (Element e : elements) {
    cell.addElement(e);
}
table.addCell(cell);
document.add(table);
```

This is due to a limitation in the `ColumnText` class that has been there for many years. We have evaluated the problem and the only way to fix this, would be to rewrite `ColumnText` entirely. This is not an item on our current technical road map.

Comment: I need to fill an existing PDF with richtext data, I was allowed to render the overflown data in a new page, how can I do that without using ColumnText go. For document.add, what happened to the cutoff text, how can I split the text to fit in pages. I'm sorry if this question is too obvious to you, I just started using itext.

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand. Please create a new question and include an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that explains what you're trying to do, and explain why you think that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround for nested ordered and un-ordered lists.

The rich Text editor I am using giving the class attribute "ql-indent-1/2/2/" for li tags, based on the attribute adding ul/ol starting and ending tags.

```
public String replaceIndentSubList(String htmlContent) {
    org.jsoup.nodes.Document document = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(htmlContent);
    Elements element_UL = document.select("ul");
    Elements element_OL = document.select("ol");
    if (!element_UL.isEmpty()) {
        htmlContent = replaceIndents(htmlContent, element_UL, "ul");
    }
    if (!element_OL.isEmpty()) {
        htmlContent = replaceIndents(htmlContent, element_OL, "ol");
    }
    return htmlContent;
}


public String replaceIndents(String htmlContent, Elements element, String tagType) {
    String attributeKey = "class";
    String startingULTgas = "<" + tagType + ">";
    String endingULTags = "</" + tagType + ">";
    int lengthOfQLIndenet = new String("ql-indent-").length();
    HashMap<String, String> startingLiTagMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, String> lastLiTagMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("ql-indent-\\d");
    HashSet<String> hash_Set = new HashSet<String>();
    Elements element_Tag = element.select("li");
    for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element element2 : element_Tag) {
        org.jsoup.nodes.Attributes att = element2.attributes();
        if (att.hasKey(attributeKey)) {
            String attributeValue = att.get(attributeKey);
            Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(attributeValue);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                if (!startingLiTagMap.containsKey(attributeValue)) {
                    startingLiTagMap.put(attributeValue, element2.toString());
                }
                hash_Set.add(matcher.group(0));
                if (!startingLiTagMap.get(attributeValue)
                        .equalsIgnoreCase(element2.toString())) {
                    lastLiTagMap.put(attributeValue, element2.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(htmlContent);
    Iterator value = hash_Set.iterator();
    while (value.hasNext()) {
        String liAttributeKey = (String) value.next();
        int noOfIndentes = Integer
                .parseInt(liAttributeKey.substring(lengthOfQLIndenet));
        if (noOfIndentes > 1)
            for (int i = 1; i < noOfIndentes; i++) {
                startingULTgas = startingULTgas + "<" + tagType + ">";
                endingULTags = endingULTags + "</" + tagType + ">";
            }
        htmlContent = htmlContent.replace(startingLiTagMap.get(liAttributeKey),
                startingULTgas + startingLiTagMap.get(liAttributeKey));
        if (lastLiTagMap.get(liAttributeKey) != null) {
            System.out.println("Inside last Li Map");
            htmlContent = htmlContent.replace(lastLiTagMap.get(liAttributeKey),
                    lastLiTagMap.get(liAttributeKey) + endingULTags);
        }
        else {
            htmlContent = htmlContent.replace(startingLiTagMap.get(liAttributeKey),
                    startingLiTagMap.get(liAttributeKey) + endingULTags);
        }
        startingULTgas = "<" + tagType + ">";
        endingULTags = "</" + tagType + ">";
    }
    System.out.println(htmlContent);[enter image description here][1]
    return htmlContent;
}
```