# Nested List rendering issue with ColumnText, alternative for ColumnText?

Tags: itext

(code in itextsharp but question is to both itext and itext sharp)

I tried to use 
`XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(mh, sr);` to convert a richtext field to PDF. But it failed in converting nested lists.

```
    <ul>
        <li>
            test1
            <ul>
                <li>test1.1</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>test2</li>
    </ul>
```

is rendered as

- test1 test1.1
- test2

So I searched around and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755315/how-can-i-convert-xhtml-nested-list-to-pdf-with-itext)

Then someone mention in the post above that nested list will not work for a ColumnText, which I need to use to fill text that can overflown to next page.

```
ct.AddElement(par);
int status = 0;
status = ct.Go();

if (ColumnText.HasMoreText(status))
{
    // add new page and continue filling columntext
}
```

I guess my question is besides ColumnText, what else that I can use which renders nested lists well that can deal with overflown richtext PDF field

Edit: we are using itextsharp 5.5.10. not sure if it is fixed in itext 7

Comment: Found a log [link]http://itextpdf.com/changelog/556 and a jira number  SUP-879 but not sure the status of it. If not using ColumnText, what can I use to generate pdf field that can overflown to next page

Comment: I'm just thinking if I can use columntext just as a way to measure the fit, then cut the element list with the ones that fits in the columntext. I know that I have the y position after columntext go, how can I cut the piece(element) that fits before y then use document to write instead of columntext